# R Combine various logical operators within Boolean or if statements

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a dataframe listing 400 Products. Each of these Products belong to a certain category: BODY CLEANSING, HAIR, DEO, HAND BODY, FACE, MEN, LIP, SUN and FEMALE SHAVE. Furthermore I have the Sales Month, in which each of the 400 Products were launched.

I want to create a new column in my dataframe displaying `TRUE` if the product was launched in high season and `FALSE` if not.

The logic is something like this:
If a product in the cateogry BODY CLEANSING or HAIR or DEO or HAND BODY or FACE or MEN or LIP was launched in the months of October or November or December high season = `TRUE` and if a product in the category SUN or FEMALE SHAVE is launched in the months of either April, May, June or July high season = `TRUE`.

I have tried the following:

```
Sample_15$high_season <- (Sample_15$Category == "BODY CLEANSING" | "HAIR" 
| "DEO" | "HAND BODY"| "FACE" | "MEN" | "LIP" & Sample_15$Months_extract 
== "Oktober" | "November" | "Dezember") | (Sample_15$Category == "SUN" | 
"FEMALE SHAVE" & Sample_15$Months_extract == "April" |                                              
"Mai" | "Juni" | "Juli")
```

And I get this Error message:

```
Error in Sample_15$Category == "BODY CLEANSING" | "HAIR" : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

Does anybody know how to code the logic of the Boolean? Any help is appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 0):

`Sample_15$Category == "BODY CLEANSING" | Sample_15$Category == "HAIR"` ... and so on

or

```
Sample_15$Category %in% c("BODY CLEANSING","HAIR",...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer @user2974951. I have tried to correct that. The Boolean gets messed up however. E.g. FACE category and Month January is TRUE which makes no sense. Am I also messing up the syntax with the logical operators?

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you don't write again the vector font of all conditions as 
user2974951 showed you. In your case it is easier to check if an element is inside a vector.

In term of solution, an easy way to solve this is to use `dplyr` and `case_when` :

```
Sample15 %>% 
mutate(high_season = case_when(
    Category %in% c("BODY CLEANSING","HAIR", "DEO","HAND BODY","FACE","MEN","LIP") 
    & Months_extract %in% c("Oktober","November" ,"Dezember") ~ TRUE, 

    Category %in% c("SUN" ,"FEMALE SHAVE") 
    & Months_extract %in% c("April","Mai","Juni", "Juli") ~ TRUE)) %>% 

mutate(high_season = ifelse(highseason == TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)) #add FALSE to rest
```

With base R (not tidy)

```
hsm <- which(Sample15$Category %in% c("BODY CLEANSING","HAIR", "DEO","HAND BODY","FACE","MEN","LIP") 
        & Sample15$Months_extract %in% c("Oktober","November" ,"Dezember")) 

Sample15[hsm,high_season] <- TRUE 

hsf <- which(Sample15$Category %in% c("SUN" ,"FEMALE SHAVE") 
        & Sample15$Months_extract %in% c("April","Mai","Juni", "Juli"))

Sample15[hsf,high_season] <- TRUE 

Sample15$highseason <- ifelse(Sample15$high_season == TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am having problems loading the dplyr package. I rely on base for the moment being. I think I am messing up something with the brackets in my code. I will post the question again but framed in a different way.