# How to combine several conditions with logical operators for a Boolean vector or if statement

Tags: r, if-statement, boolean, logical-operators

I have the following dataframe:

```
Category <- rep(c("FACE", "LIP", "BODY", "HAIR", "SUN"), each = 2)
Month <- c("October", "Janurary", "April", "Feburary", "November", 
"August", "October", "May", "June", "December")
df2 <- data.frame(Category, Month)

  Category    Month
1      FACE  Oktober
2      FACE Janurary
3       LIP    April
4       LIP Feburary
5      BODY November
6      BODY   August
7      HAIR  October
8      HAIR      May
9       SUN     June
10      SUN December
```

I want to add another column "high season" = TRUE if Category FACE, LIP, BODY or HAIR are in Month Oktober, November or December and if Category SUN is in April, May, June or July.

The result should thus look like this:

```
   Category    Month high_season_result
1      FACE  October               TRUE
2      FACE Janurary              FALSE
3       LIP    April              FALSE
4       LIP Feburary              FALSE
5      BODY November               TRUE
6      BODY   August              FALSE
7      HAIR  October               TRUE
8      HAIR      May              FALSE
9       SUN     June               TRUE
10      SUN December              FALSE
```

I have tried this code:

```
df2$high_season <- (df2$Category == "FACE" & ((df2$Month == "October") | 
(df2$Month == "November") | (df2$Month == "December"))) | (df2$Month == 
"BODY" & ((df2$Month == "October") | (df2$Month == "November") |                       
(df2$Month == "December"))) | (df2$Category == "LIP" &                                                       
((df2$Month == "October") |                                                            
(df2$Month == "November") |                                                            
(df2$Month == "December"))) | 
  (df2$Category == "HAIR" & ((df2$Month == "October") | (df2$Month == 
November") | (df2$Month == "December"))) | (df2$Month == "SUN" &                                                              
((df2$Month == "April") |                                               
(df2$Month == "May") |                                                             
(df2$Month == "June") |                                                               
(df2$Month == "July")))
```

The Boolean gets messed up:

```
   Category    Month high_season
1      FACE  October        TRUE
2      FACE Janurary       FALSE
3       LIP    April       FALSE
4       LIP Feburary       FALSE
5      BODY November       FALSE
6      BODY   August       FALSE
7      HAIR  October        TRUE
8      HAIR      May       FALSE
9       SUN     June       FALSE
10      SUN December       FALSE
```

I have tried to remove brackets in the code, the Boolean changes then but still it is not the correct result. I suspect that I am messing it up with the brackets or with the logical operators.

Can someone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57753892/r-combine-various-logical-operators-within-boolean-or-if-statements

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```r
season <- c('FACE', 'LIP', 'BODY', 'HAIR')
month1 <- c('Oktober', 'November', 'December', 'October')
sun <- c('April', 'May', 'June', 'July')
#df2$high_season <- ifelse((df2$Category %in% season &(df2$Month %in%month1) | (df2$Category == 'SUN' & df2$Month %in% sun)), TRUE, FALSE)
df2$high_season <- df2$Category %in% season &(df2$Month %in%month1) | (df2$Category == 'SUN' & df2$Month %in% sun)
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

#       Category    Month     high_season
# 1      FACE       October   TRUE
# 2      FACE       Janurary  FALSE
# 3       LIP       April     FALSE
# 4       LIP       Feburary  FALSE
# 5      BODY       November  TRUE
# 6      BODY       August    FALSE
# 7      HAIR       October   TRUE
# 8      HAIR       May       FALSE
# 9       SUN       June      TRUE
# 10      SUN       December  FALSE
```

Comment: you don't need `ifelse` here `df2$Category %in% season & (df2$Month %in% month1) | (df2$Category == 'SUN' & df2$Month %in% sun)`  is already giving you a logical vector.

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah, out of curiosity though, does the `ifelse()` introduce additional efficiency load?

Comment: I am not sure but it looks like extra code when it is not necessary.

Comment: `ifelse` is slower because it creates vectors the same size of the condition for both the `yes` part and the `no` part.

Comment: Agreed, extra and makes the script verbose.  Started the solution with `ifelse()` without realizing the `%in%` returns a logical vector. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with logical vectors instead of a long logical condition.

```
i1 <- df2$Category %in% c("FACE", "LIP", "BODY", "HAIR")
j1 <- df2$Month %in% c("October", "November", "December")
i2 <- df2$Category %in% "SUN"
j2 <- df2$Month %in% c("April", "May", "June", "July")
df2$high_season_result <- (i1 & j1) | (i2 & j2)

df2
#   Category    Month high_season_result
#1      FACE  October               TRUE
#2      FACE Janurary              FALSE
#3       LIP    April              FALSE
#4       LIP Feburary              FALSE
#5      BODY November               TRUE
#6      BODY   August              FALSE
#7      HAIR  October               TRUE
#8      HAIR      May              FALSE
#9       SUN     June               TRUE
#10      SUN December              FALSE
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks! I am having problems loading the dplyr package, but I coded the same logic using R base and it worked perfectly fine!

Comment: @Morasc why do you need to load `dplyr` package?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem using vectors as suggested by @Rui Barradas but using R base instead of dplyr package:

```
Cat1 <- df2$Category == "FACE" | df2$Category == "LIP" | df2$Category == "BODY" | 
df2$Category == "HAIR"
Mo1 <- df2$Month == "October" | df2$Month == "November" | df2$Month == "December"
Cat2 <- df2$Category == "SUN"
Mo2 <- df2$Month == "April" | df2$Month == "May" | df2$Month == "June" | df2$Month == 
"July"
df2$high_season_result <- (Cat1 & Mo1) | (Cat2 & Mo2)

   Category    Month high_season_result
1      FACE  October               TURE
2      FACE Janurary              FALSE
3       LIP    April              FALSE
4       LIP Feburary              FALSE
5      BODY November               TURE
6      BODY   August              FALSE
7      HAIR  October               TRUE
8      HAIR      May              FALSE
9       SUN     June               TRUE
10      SUN December              FALSE
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Instead of combining several `==` with logical `|`, use `%in%` like in my answer.